# java external file reading

Tags: java, file

I have a java program that needs to read `program.cfg` file at starting, that holding in directory with jar of this program, but when I'm using this:

```
File file = new File("/res/meissa.cfg");
```

program trying to find this file in the jar file of program.
How to define file, holding not in jar file, but in directory with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "yourFile.ext");
```

And done.